# Crash in sending attachment to conversation in iMessage app extension iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10

I have built a sample iMessage app extension in iOS 10 which sends PDF file to the conversation. I get the PDF download link from a web service and send it as attachment like this:

```
self.activeConversation?.insertAttachment(url, withAlternateFilename: file.name, completionHandler: nil)
```

Once I call this message, the iMessage app crash in simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I should pass a file URL for a local file in bundle or local disk. You can't pass a remote file URL.

In my case I've downloaded the file first and wrote it to Document path and passed a the local path to `insertAttachment` method and it works fine.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation states that it should be a file path : https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msconversation/1648184-insertattachment#parameters